# PowerShell script Error Directory Name is invalid

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, powershell-4.0

I am trying to invoke a power shell script using task scheduler but it gives me the error, The directory name is invalid Error (0x8007010B).

I have tried placing the script in C: and C:\users and also D:
But the error remains.

I have tried adding and removing the quotes in the location specification but the issue remains the same.
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McciU.png)

Here are the arguments and the exact directory path of the PowerShell script to be run.

```
Add arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File
Start in: D:\automationscripts\RestartTomcat.ps1
```

Permissions of the directory:[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCc3Z.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCWU6.png)

Here is the update after changing the parameters of the Arguments and Start in
[Update1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQVQ2.png)

Comment: Are we supposed to guess the rest of the argument and start location values?

Comment: Are you sure that the account trying to run the script has Read access to the location the script is saved?

Comment: Added the details for the same

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is just a scheduled task syntax issue. You need the file name in your arguments, and the Start In to just be the folder location. So your action would be:

Program: PowerShell.exe
Arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File RestartTomcat.ps1
Start in: D:\automationscripts

Comment: This is the result when I use the arguments provided
Last Run Result: 0xFFFD0000